# Laravel Eloquent - Ordering by specific ID of the child

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 3 models: `Schedule`, `Shift`, and `User`. A `Schedule` has many `Shift`, and each `Shift` belongs to a `Schedule` and has one `User`.

To get my schedule (with shifts and user), I use:

```
Schedule::with(['shifts', 'shifts.user'])->find($id);
```

I want to order this schedule by a specific user `id` - i.e. if you are looking at a schedule, I want your shift to be the first one on the schedule.

All I could find online was how to order the parent Eloquent model (i.e. `Schedule` here) using `orderByRaw()`

```
User::orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $user_id)"));
```

I tried to put this in the `$query` of the `with` statement, but this didn't work:

```
Schedule::with(
    [
        'shifts', 
        'shifts.user' => function($query) use ($user_id)
        {
            $query->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(id, $user_id)"));
        }
    ])->find($id);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does a `User` have one `Schedule`? If you added this relation, this would be much easier.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. There is a schedule for each given day, with shifts assigned to every individual. So ever day's schedule's shift belongs to a `User`.

Comment: As far as I know that, you can't do it this way but you can use `join` and then `orderby`.

Comment: **`with` runs another query for each relation** so you **can't** order by related table with it. Use `joins` OR sort the collection you get as a result from the query.